# PostgreSQL format lag column

Tags: postgresql, lag

This query works great for finding the difference between successive rows:

```
select id, created_at, created_at - lag(created_at, 1) 
over (order by created_at) as diff
from fistbumps where bumper_id = 2543 
and created_at between '2012-01-11' and '2012-01-12' order by created_at;
```

...but the results come out like:

```
   id   |         created_at         |      diff       
--------+----------------------------+-----------------
 197230 | 2012-01-11 00:04:31.774426 | 
 197231 | 2012-01-11 00:04:32.279181 | 00:00:00.504755
 197232 | 2012-01-11 00:04:33.961665 | 00:00:01.682484
 197233 | 2012-01-11 00:04:36.506685 | 00:00:02.54502
```

What would be really groovy is if I could format that diff column to just seconds and millis (e.g. 2.54502). I tried using date_trunc() and extract(), but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of created_at - lag(create_at) is a value of type `interval`.

You can get the seconds of an `interval` using `extract(epoch from interval_value)`

So in your case it would be:

```
extract(epoch from (created_at - lag(created_at, 1)) )
```

Comment: It returns seconds, not milliseconds.